# Code Isolation: Windows AppContainer vs. Docker

Tags: docker, isolation, appcontainer

My goal is to compile and execute a user inputted script (C# to start with but may expand to other languages) in an isolated environment to guard against malicious code.

I first considered .NET AppDomains as I had some familiarity with them but discovered they have been deprecated and have been found to be vulnerable to exploitation under certain conditions.

This led me to Windows AppContainers. However, I've found them to be quite unwieldly and there doesn't seem to be a ton of documentation or articles surrounding them. This leads me to believe they are not a popular, which makes me wary to employ them myself.

As such, I've thought to consider Docker as an alternative as its usage is quite widespread.

I've searched for comparison articles but have come up short so I was hoping someone in the know might be able to give me pros and cons of each approach (from a security and performance perspective).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any requirements for the server OS or the environment?  In case you are restricted to Windows host, please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/hyperv-container for more background information on alternatives, first.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I will be running on a Windows host. Thanks for that article, it seems that the option of using Hyper-V to achieve even more isolation is a big pro for Docker.